# How to solve singular gradient matrix error?

Tags: r, regression, non-linear-regression

I'm creating a non-linear regression model to fit the data below

Plot

[image]

I keep on getting the error:

> *singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates*

Can anyone explain what's wrong with my model? The equation I'm trying to write is `y = (p1*logbasep2 (x))/(x^p3)`, where `p1`, `p2`, and `p3` are constants.

```
p1 <- 1
p2 <- 1 
p3 <- 2


model1 = nls(ydata ~ ((p1*log(xdata, p3))/(xdata)^p2), start = list(p1 = p1, p2 = p2, p3 = p3))
```

Below is the sample output for xdata and ydata

```
  > dput(ydata)
c(2.675967443, 5.262229596, 2.756358345, 2.582628563, 2.578517983, 
2.572149035, 2.572149035, 2.419269246, 4.342393324, 4.57849526, 
2.414960542, 2.414960542, 2.414960542, 2.414960542, 2.655729394, 
5.205391565, 3.137641723, 2.503911184, 2.499359843, 2.499198257, 
2.498768034, 2.693594595, 5.231803091, 2.998312831, 2.520387095, 
2.518634129, 2.518634129, 2.518634129, 2.711184536, 5.229303652, 
3.003137243, 2.551123783, 2.516552812, 2.504450358, 2.484247615, 
2.581875759, 5.157438135, 3.310365728, 2.620786825, 2.458420168, 
2.436577883, 2.434535502, 2.606225185, 5.265676214, 2.71775484, 
2.61596361, 2.598126717, 2.598126717, 2.598126717, 2.803018082, 
4.934368949, 3.595430381, 3.031594421, 2.227695807, 2.207278748, 
2.200613613, 2.594364366, 5.215228585, 3.07169941, 2.694566482, 
2.511361391, 2.456389883, 2.456389883, 2.862120485, 5.202934582, 
3.056182323, 2.469690653, 2.469690653, 2.469690653, 2.469690653, 
2.437314286, 4.587186915, 4.302037827, 2.711703229, 2.346318322, 
2.308501078, 2.306938344, 2.30614524, 4.657971143, 4.158221237, 
2.943632973, 2.350070603, 2.296930829, 2.287027975, 2.531924554, 
5.071156271, 3.541488012, 2.65287316, 2.420471714, 2.391688, 
2.39039829, 2.477102765, 5.030773262, 3.642446383, 2.620965051, 
2.424021444, 2.402895805, 2.40179529, 2.584714789, 5.03335416, 
3.619673092, 2.583602564, 2.533903128, 2.326437301, 2.318314966, 
2.49144927, 4.897950266, 3.585821617, 3.227165648, 2.53767512, 
2.221395797, 2.038542282, 2.354867369, 4.95865857, 3.766909175, 
2.715186396, 2.382613432, 2.372757351, 2.449007707, 2.20573524, 
4.55514547, 3.91611881, 3.606189025, 2.303604277, 2.20810652, 
2.205100659, 3.300879888, 5.151795375, 2.75624017, 2.449071065, 
2.447337834, 2.447337834, 2.447337834, 2.528936269, 4.955034368, 
3.754254308, 2.751181588, 2.399415789, 2.308263059, 2.302914619, 
2.350317116, 4.873892721, 3.39391574, 2.606991064, 2.443820718, 
2.33106264, 2.33106264, 2.621925026, 5.267786769, 2.622588101, 
2.621925026, 2.621925026, 2.621925026, 2.621925026, 2.425160063, 
5.022138529, 3.663550495, 2.612718078, 2.425326541, 2.42594623, 
2.425160063, 2.625820509, 5.265415337, 2.713068882, 2.638650782, 
2.585780084, 2.586285083, 2.584979323, 2.508232606, 4.902729122, 
3.746937795, 3.015086226, 2.332707845, 2.267248424, 2.227057981, 
2.947719346, 5.098315798, 3.368997979, 2.39886785, 2.402312015, 
2.392233622, 2.39155339, 2.548810552, 4.525931048, 4.3760105, 
2.589251919, 2.429896804, 2.281201495, 2.248897682)
dput(xdata)
c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L)
```

Comment: You need better starting values. Also from looking at your equation, when xdata is one, then ydata will be zero, irrespective of parameter value., which may make things difficult. Are you able to shate your data : if so can you edit your question with the results of `dput(ydata)` and `dput(xdata)`

Comment: ps what is `logbasep2`

Comment: by logbasep2 i mean that i want the base for the logarithm to be a parameter as well

Comment: we appreciate the effort, but please please **please** post the results of `dput()` as *text* within your question, not as a screenshot (that format is more or less useless for anyone trying to replicate your problem ...)

Comment: your `dput` output is incomplete ... (please include more than just the first three lines ...)

Comment: fixed, thanks again @BenBolker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is actually more mathematical than statistical, as it turns out.  The problem is that `log(x,b1)` and `log(x,b2)` differ only by a constant factor (`log(x,b1)` = `log(x,b2)*log(b2,b1)`).  This means that your `p1` and `p3` parameters are redundant.  So everything works if you leave out `p3` (this is just one choice of the many reasonable ways to change the formula ...)

Using `nls` with the `data` argument is preferred, as it makes it easier to do things like predict new values:

```
dd <- data.frame(x=xdata,y=ydata)
model1 = nls(y ~ ((p1*log(x))/(x)^p2),
             start = list(p1 = 1, p2 = 1),
             data=dd)
```

Now predict:

```
xvec <- seq(1,7,length=101)
par(las=1,bty="l")  ## cosmetic
plot(y~x,data=dd)
lines(xvec,predict(model1,newdata=data.frame(x=xvec)))
```

[image]

Note that there are some issues with this fit (the line systematically misses the data at both the lower and the upper end) ...

Comment: thank you for the response... so if the curve is clearly missing the data points, does that mean the function that i defined for fitting the points itself is wrong and I need to find a new polynomial/logarithmic function to fit the points?

Comment: "all models are wrong ..." (Box) -- but yes, it means you should be able to come up with a model that does better. Two obvious issues are (1) your model is anchored to zero at x=1; (2) your model goes to zero as x gets large -- both characteristics that are contradicted by your data ...

Comment: Hey Ben -- thanks again for the response.. I am having a lot of trouble finding a function to best my data. I'm not asking for specific advice, but would you say that the best approach should be to just do trial and error with different types of functions (polynomial / logarithic, etc) until I find one that goes through most of my points and is accurate?

Comment: it's a big topic.  Ideally you can think about the geometry of your data (what aspects are fitting/not being fit properly) and adjust the curves appropriately, e.g. add a vertical offset `y ~ p0+((p1*log(x))/(x)^p2)`.  Also worth thinking about the *process* that's generating your data ... http://ms.mcmaster.ca/~bolker/emdbook/chap3A.pdf might (?) be useful.